# how do you grab the latest version id from secretmanager in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the secretmanager from google and the password is on a rotation, so instead of me having to update the password, then go to the python script and change it from '3' to '4'... and then after xx days to '5'...'6'...'7'. I just want it to grab the latest one.

How would one do that?

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager

    

    
    from google.cloud import secretmanager
    project_id = "xxxxxx"
    
    secret_id = "password"
    version_id ='2'
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    secret_detail = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": secret_detail})
    data = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    password = ("{}".format(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine:

```py
versions = client.list_secret_versions(request={"parent": secret_name})
latest_version = max(versions, key=lambda version: version.create_time)
```